# Python Spreadsheet, create an accessible grid of lists

Tags: python, list, grid, spreadsheet

```
L=[None]
row=2
column=5
for i in range column:
    print(L*row)
```

The thing is that I can easily create the grid. However what I want is to access it just like a spreadsheet.

For example: now I want to change row 1, column 3 to `ABC`.

Like:

**Original**

```
[None] [None]
[None] [None]
[None] [None]
[None] [None]
[None] [None]
```

**Code Change**

```
goto(1,3)

[None] [None]
[None] [None]
[None] [None]
[None] [----]
[None] [None]

insert(ABC)

[None] [None]
[None] [None]
[None] [None]
[None] [ABC ]
[None] [None]
```

Now this is what I want to happen. I know how to create the code for `goto()` and `insert()` but I don't know how to access the grid. Can someone please tell me how to access the grid? Thank you.

Comment: what are you using to create your grid? what do you mean you insert  and you doknow how to access but you know how to insert? please put the code up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is a custom `class` that defines the methods `goto` and `insert` to behave like you just described. You could also do it using global variables and functions, but using a class makes it easier to manage and more portable.

A very simple implementation would be the following:

```
class Spreadsheet:
    def __init__(self, rows, columns):
        self.matrix = []
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.cur_pos = (0, 0)

        for i in range(rows):
            self.matrix.append([])
            for j in range(columns):
                self.matrix[i].append(None)

    def goto(self, x, y):
        if 0 <= x < self.rows and 0 <= y < self.columns:
            self.cur_pos = (x, y)
        else:
            raise Exception('Cannot goto({},{}): matrix indexes out of range!'.format(x, y))


    def insert(self, element):
        self.matrix[self.cur_pos[0]][self.cur_pos[1]] = element
```

You can then use it like this:

```
s = Spreadsheet(5, 2)
s.goto(3, 1)
s.insert('ABC')

for line in s.matrix:
    print(line)
```

The result would be:

```
[None, None]
[None, None]
[None, None]
[None, 'ABC']
[None, None]
```